# How to install nodejs on Gentoo Base System version 1.6.14?

Tags: linux, node.js, gentoo

I tried
1) emerge nodejs

```
!!! ARCH is not set... Are you missing the '/etc/make.profile' symlink?
!!! Is the symlink correct? Is your portage tree complete?
```

2) downloading from Linux Binaries nodejs (tried both 32 and 64bits)

```
bin # ./node
Exception en point flottant
```

3) from code source:

```
Waf: Leaving directory `/node-v0.4.10/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
        {task: cxx_link node_main_4.o,node_4.o,node_buffer_4.o,node_javascript_4.o,node_extensions_4.o,node_http_parser_4.o,node_net_4.o,node_io_watcher_4.o,node_constants_4.o,node_cares_4.o,node_events_4.o,node_file_4.o,node_signal_watcher_4.o,node_stat_watcher_4.o,node_timer_4.o,node_script_4.o,node_os_4.o,node_dtrace_4.o,node_string_4.o,node_stdio_4.o,node_child_process_4.o,platform_linux_4.o,node_crypto_4.o,eio_1.o,http_parser_2.o,ev_1.o,ares_strcasecmp_1.o,ares_free_string_1.o,ares_options_1.o,ares_send_1.o,ares_parse_txt_reply_1.o,ares_parse_ptr_reply_1.o,ares_nowarn_1.o,ares_search_1.o,ares_gethostbyname_1.o,ares_getsock_1.o,ares__timeval_1.o,inet_ntop_1.o,ares_parse_a_reply_1.o,ares_getopt_1.o,ares__close_sockets_1.o,ares_expand_string_1.o,ares_destroy_1.o,ares_cancel_1.o,ares_parse_aaaa_reply_1.o,ares_parse_ns_reply_1.o,ares_version_1.o,ares__get_hostent_1.o,ares_writev_1.o,ares_expand_name_1.o,ares_free_hostent_1.o,ares_parse_mx_reply_1.o,ares_gethostbyaddr_1.o,ares_llist_1.o,ares_data_1.o,ares_init_1.o,ares_fds_1.o,inet_net_pton_1.o,ares_strerror_1.o,bitncmp_1.o,ares_getnameinfo_1.o,ares_library_init_1.o,ares_mkquery_1.o,ares_process_1.o,windows_port_1.o,ares_parse_srv_reply_1.o,ares_query_1.o,ares_timeout_1.o,ares__read_line_1.o,ares_strdup_1.o -> node}
make: *** [program] Erreur 1
```

What else could I try ?
Is there a ready to go precompiled for gentoo 64 bits ?

regards

Comment: Did you try to install node v0.4? It's like 2y old. Try with the latest sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error about ARCH not being set, than you really need to resolve it first before attempting to install more packages.

So, how well maintained is your current box?
At a minimum, see if the following helps:
a) eselect profile list, eselect profile set 
b) Make sure that your customizations to /etc/make.conf are in that file and the contents look correct.
c) emerge --sync

I'm guessing your portage tree is out of sync and that updating it via emerge --sync is the real issue.  However, if you are so far out of date, you'll have other issues you'll need to address to bring the box current.  Gentoo systems are supposed to be updated at least once/year at a minimum, preferably once/month.

Otherwise, as far as node.js goes:
0.10.21 is the latest stable in the tree, go ahead and retry by selecting that package for install.

emerge -v =net-libs/nodejs-0.10.21